# Implementing a filter for a SQL query in a Rails app

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

This is a rails app that uses Vue as front-end. There are 2 similar models/tables, named `user_notifications` and `seller_notifications`, that have the same columns.

In the `user_notifications_controller` there are 2 distinct actions, one that shows only user_notifications (for the My Notifications page) and another that shows all notifications (user+seller) [for the Notifications page].

I was not able to have the query results show what I need using ActiveRecords helpers, so I decided to make it directly as an SQL query. This is the original query:

```
(
  SELECT sn.id, sellers.name, sn.seller_id AS member_id, sn.title, sn.body, sn.created_at, sn.is_new, sellers.platform_id, sn.pending_action_id, 'seller_notifications' AS type
  FROM seller_notifications sn
  INNER JOIN sellers ON sellers.id = sn.seller_id
  WHERE sn.platform_id = :platform_id
  ORDER BY sn.created_at DESC
) UNION ALL (
  SELECT un.id, users.name, un.user_id AS member_id, un.title, un.body, un.created_at, un.is_new, users.platform_id, un.pending_action_id, 'user_notifications' AS type
  FROM user_notifications un
  INNER JOIN users ON users.id = un.user_id
  WHERE un.platform_id = :platform_id
  ORDER BY un.created_at DESC
)
LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset
```

The issue is that I need to include a filter, which I have done and it works fine for the most part except one: the type (where table's name is), because I need to be able to filter for what kind of notification it is.

Below is the complete code, including query sanitizer:

```
query = "(
SELECT sn.id, sellers.name, sn.seller_id AS member_id, sn.title, sn.body, sn.created_at, sn.is_new, sellers.platform_id, sn.pending_action_id, 'seller_notifications' AS type FROM seller_notifications sn
INNER JOIN sellers ON sellers.id = sn.seller_id
WHERE sn.platform_id = :platform_id #{params[:is_new].nil? ? nil : ' AND sn.is_new = :is_new '}
#{params[:member_id].nil? ? nil : ' AND sn.seller_id = :member_id '}
#{params[:title].nil? ? nil : ' AND sn.title = :title '}
ORDER BY sn.created_at DESC)
UNION ALL
(SELECT un.id, users.name, un.user_id AS member_id, un.title, un.body, un.created_at, un.is_new, users.platform_id, un.pending_action_id, 'user_notifications' AS type FROM user_notifications un
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = un.user_id
WHERE un.platform_id = :platform_id #{params[:is_new].nil? ? nil : ' AND un.is_new = :is_new '}
#{params[:member_id].nil? ? nil : ' AND un.user_id = :member_id '}
#{params[:title].nil? ? nil : ' AND un.title = :title '}
ORDER BY un.created_at DESC)
LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset"

sanitizer_ary = [
  query,
  platform_id: @user.platform_id,
  limit: limit,
  offset: offset,
  member_id: params[:member_id],
  title:  params[:title],   name: params[:name],
  type: params[:type],
  is_new: params[:is_new]
  ]

sanitized_query = ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, sanitizer_ary)
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sanitized_query)
result.map { |notif| notif }
```

When I originally tried to query it as `WHERE type = :type` it raises an PG::Error that I believe it's because of the lack of table prefix, e.g. `un.type` instead of just `type`, but there is no column named type. I have also tried placing the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` statements outside of the parenthesis at the end, just before `LIMIT`, but it also raises PostgreSQL statement error.
So far, none of what I tried has worked.

ERRORS
This is the original error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "type" does not exist
LINE 3:       WHERE sn.platform_id = 1 AND type = NULL 
                                           ^
 excluded from capture: DSN not set
  
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "type" does not exist
LINE 3:       WHERE sn.platform_id = 1 AND type = NULL 
                                           ^
):
```

And this is when I tried to use the WHERE statement outside of the parenthesis:

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 14:       WHERE type = NULL
               ^
 excluded from capture: DSN not set
  
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 14:       WHERE type = NULL
               ^
):
```

EXPECTATION
What I need is to be able to include a line, similar to the one below, just after the `params[:title]` line:

```
#{params[:type].nil? ? nil : ' AND type = :type'}
```

Does anybody know how to solve this, i.e.: filter a query result that includes the name of the table by the name of the table itself, which is not included in the table's columns??

Comment: At this point, you want to merge the two tables together and your queries will become much much simpler.

Comment: "I have also tried placing the WHERE and ORDER BY statements outside of the parenthesis at the end, just before LIMIT, but it also raises PostgreSQL statement error" - and rightly so, because that would be an invalid statement. Do another select on the result of the union. `select * from (select ... union select ...) where type = 'seller_notification'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider creating a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html) of the union of the two tables.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW unified_notifications AS
   SELECT 
      sn.id, 
      sellers.name, 
      sn.seller_id AS member_id, 
      sn.title, 
      sn.body, 
      sn.created_at, 
      sn.is_new, 
      sellers.platform_id, 
      sn.pending_action_id, 
      'seller_notifications' AS type 
   FROM seller_notifications sn
   INNER JOIN sellers ON sellers.id = sn.seller_id
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 
     un.id, 
     users.name, 
     un.user_id AS member_id, 
     un.title, 
     un.body, 
     un.created_at, 
     un.is_new, 
     users.platform_id, 
     un.pending_action_id, 
     'user_notifications' AS type 
   FROM user_notifications un
   INNER JOIN users ON users.id = un.user_id
```

The [scenic gem](https://github.com/scenic-views/scenic) can be used to create views with Rails migrations. Note that you need to switch to SQL schema dumps.

Since the view behaves like a table (at least from the perspective of ActiveRecord) you can just create an ActiveRecord model and query it like it was a single table:

```
class UnifiedNotification < ApplicationRecord
  def readonly?
    true
   end
end

UnifiedNotification.where(
  platform_id: @user.platform_id,
  # ...
)
```

Comment: that's a great idea, I always forget about materialized views.

Comment: I appreciate this answer very much, but I tried Sergio idea in the comment above and it worked, so I'll be using it.

Answer (score -2):

If you express your relations cleanly using ActiveRecord, then the queries will express themselves..

```
class SellerNotification < ApplicationRecord                                                                                                                                                                                      
  belongs_to :platform
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: "Seller", inverse_of: :notifications
                                
  scope :plaftorms, ->(*p) {                                                    
    p = p.flatten.compact.uniq                                                  
                                                                                
    p.any? where(plaform_id: p) : none                                          
  }                                                                             
                                                                                
  scope :title, ->(title) {                                                     
    where(title: title)                                                         
  }                                                                             
                                                                                
  scope :members, ->(*members) {                                                
    members = members.flatten.compact.uniq                                      
                                                                                
    members.any? ? where(user_id: members) : none                               
  }                                                                             
end                                                                             
                                                                                
class Seller < ApplicationRecord                                                               
  has_many :notifications, class_name: "SellerNotification", dependent: :destroy
    
  scope :platforms, ->(*p) {
    joins(:nofifications)
      .merge(SellerNotification.platforms(*p))
  }
    
 end
```

Comment: You're not actually answing the question here which is that he wants to query a union of two almost identical tables.